# Numpy.append aplana el resultado a pesar de usar axis=0 para que añada nuevas filas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Intento anexar nuevas filas usando `numpy.append`, pero en lugar de eso aplana el resultado como si `axis` fuera `None`, a pesar de usar `axis=0`.

```
datos = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 8, 11, 17, 20],
[3, 8, 12, 13, 15, 18],
[1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12],
[3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 16],
[4, 5, 7, 8, 17, 20]])

valores = np.empty(0, int)
for v in datos.values:
    lista = np.zeros(20, int)
    for vv in v:
        lista[vv - 1] = 1
    valores = np.append(valores, lista, axis=0)

    print(v, valores)
```

Y el resultado es una concatenación aplanada en cada paso, en vez de añadir las filas como era de esperar...

`[ 4  5  8 11 17 20] [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]`

`[ 3  8 12 13 15 18] [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]`

`[ 1  3  4  7 11 12] [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

Etc.

Por cierto, si hago lo siguiente funciona como es de esperar:

`print(np.append([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9]], axis=0))`

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

¿Alguna idea de dónde puede estar mi error...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.append` se comporta como cabe esperar, porque tanto `valores` como `lista` son **dos arrays unidimensionales**:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> arr
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.append(arr, np.array([4, 5, 6]), axis=0)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Para obtener el resultado que deseas debes usar arrays de dos dimensiones en ambos casos:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> np.append(arr, np.array([[4, 5, 6]]), axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Es decir, tu código debería ser algo como:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datos = pd.DataFrame([
    [4, 5, 8, 11, 17, 20],
    [3, 8, 12, 13, 15, 18],
    [1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12],
    [3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 16],
    [4, 5, 7, 8, 17, 20]
])

valores = np.empty((0, 20), int)
for v in datos.values:
    lista = np.zeros((1, 20), int)
    for vv in v:
        lista[0, vv - 1] = 1
    valores = np.append(valores, lista, axis=0)

    print(v, valores)
```

Ten en cuenta que `np.append` es una operación muy costosa dado que necesita crear un nuevo array en memoria cada vez. Esto llega a tal punto en casos como el que planteas que usar listas de python y crear el array al final del ciclo es más eficiente. En tu caso, si tu ejemplo es representativo de tu problema real (conoces el número de filas del array antes de iterar), una forma mas simple y mucho mas eficiente (aún usando el ciclo `for`) seria simplemente crear  el array al inicio con todas las filas necesarias y prescindir de `append`:

```
valores = np.zeros((datos.shape[0], 20), int)
for indice, fila in datos.iterrows():
    for valor in fila:
        valores[indice, valor - 1] = 1
```